# Table(s) indexing strategy for separable data

Tags: postgresql, index, mongodb

**Scenario:** The data needs to be indexed by location, all of the rows include location info and also city info. I want to index by location, but there are millions of rows. The idea is that I can create other tables, for each city and I can index again by location.

I know that there are options such as Sharding and Partitioning however, I'd like to learn more before going further.

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    t1 
INNER JOIN 
    t2
ON 
    t1.locationId = t2.locationId
 WHERE 
    t1.locationId = '.....';
```

..~ (1-2K result)

After indexing by locationId (in both two tables), the first query returns data after ~900ms,subsequent queries takes ~20ms. However, since there's a lot of locationId, I think it's not possible to cache all of them, and this will not work.

Any other idea is appreciated.

Comment: This is too general. Please provide the `CREATE TABLE` statements and the query you are experimenting with.

Comment: I can't share the exact query but basically, two tables share locationid. I've edited the question. Thanks! @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: Thanks. And the other alternative?

Comment: What's the relationship between `location` and `city`?  I'm confused by this statement: "The idea is that I can create other tables, for each city and I can index again by location."  Sample data would be helpful.

Comment: I did not try it. In that scenario, t1 and t2 have cityId. So I might create other tables like t1_id1, t1_id2, and t2_id1 t2_id2. Consequently, in the application, I can get the city id and query that table corresponding to that id. So, instead of searching in millions of rows I can search thousands. But this will also slow probably, so I can index by location id again in all city tables. Finally, the question is if I'm going to index again, does it matter if the table has thousans or millions of rows?

Comment: Your question is very confusing. What do you mean by "data in a single table can be distributed and indexed in different tables"?  "would it be more efficient than the index made in the same table" - what means *the same table*?

Comment: In general MongoDB (and other NoSQL databases) are not optimized for joins, some NoSQL even do not support joins at all. Your question does not make much sense.

Comment: I've tried to explain it above your comment. "Same" table means "single table". From that single table, I can create many tables by city and drop that single one. I know, that NoSQL is not optimized for joins, however, Mongo has $lookup, probably the winner here will be PosteSQL but the question is more about the correct data model. @WernfriedDomscheit

Comment: Partitioning your table will not make your RAM grow or your disk go faster. The question is confusing so I have pretty much no idea what you want, but "the first query returns data after ~900ms,subsequent queries takes ~20ms" hints you need more NVME SSDs and more sticks of RAM.

Comment: Sorry, let me try to clear a bit. id user_id location_id id user_id location_id .... How would you find all users if location_id is, say some random id, if there are ~100 million of records in DB, and ~500K available location_id. If you put index to location_id you need too much RAM for example. @bobflux